# How to cut part of the text and replace each line with Python and RegEx

Tags: python, regex

*Hello, I'm a complete beginner with Python and just started learning it and using RegEx for text manipulation.
I am sorry in advance if i had broken some rules of StackOverflow*

I am making a script in Python where i would take (cut) date and time from first line and replace "Date" "TimeWindowStart" and TimeWindowEnd" on each line

```
ReportDate=03/24/2019, TimeWindowStart=18:00:00, TimeWindowEnd=20:59:59

Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000
Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000
Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000
Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000
Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000
Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000
Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000
```

I know how to select with regex date

```
([0-9][0-9]|2[0-9])/[0-9][0-9](/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])?
```

And how to select time

```
([0-9][0-9]|2[0-9]):[0-9][0-9](:[0-9][0-9])?
```

But im stuck with how to select part of the text copy it and then find text which i want to replace with **re.sub function**

so final output would look like this:

```
ReportDate=, TimeWindowStart=, TimeWindowEnd=

03/24/2019, 18:00:00, 20:59:59, Report-20190323_210000
03/24/2019, 18:00:00, 20:59:59, Report-20190323_210000
03/24/2019, 18:00:00, 20:59:59, Report-20190323_210000
03/24/2019, 18:00:00, 20:59:59, Report-20190323_210000 
03/24/2019, 18:00:00, 20:59:59, Report-20190323_210000 
03/24/2019, 18:00:00, 20:59:59, Report-20190323_210000 
03/24/2019, 18:00:00, 20:59:59, Report-20190323_210000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thing, you can specify a quantifier in regex queries, so if you want 4 numbers you don't need `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` but you can do with `[0-9]{4}`. To capture an expression you wrap it in round brackets `value=([0-9]{4})` will give you only the numbers

If you want to use `re.sub` you just need to give it a patter, a replacement string and your input string, e.g. `re.sub(pattern, replacement, string)`

Therefore:

```
import re

txt = """ReportDate=03/24/2019, TimeWindowStart=18:00:00, TimeWindowEnd=20:59:59

Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000
Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000
Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000
Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000
Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000
Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000
Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000
"""

pattern_date = 'ReportDate=([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4})'
report_date = re.findall(pattern_date, txt)[0]

pattern_time_start = 'TimeWindowStart=([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})'
start_time = re.findall(pattern_time_start, txt)[0]

pattern_time_end = 'TimeWindowEnd=([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})'
end_time = re.findall(pattern_time_end, txt)[0]

splitted = txt.split('\n')  # Split the txt so that we skip the first line

txt2 = '\n'.join(splitted[1:])  # text to perform the sub 

# substitution of your values
txt2 = re.sub('Date', report_date, txt2)
txt2 = re.sub('TimeWindowStart', start_time, txt2)
txt2 = re.sub('TimeWindowEnd', end_time, txt2)

txt_final = splitted[0] + '\n' + txt2
print(txt_final)
```

Output:

```
ReportDate=03/24/2019, TimeWindowStart=18:00:00, TimeWindowEnd=20:59:59

03/24/2019, 18:00:00, 20:59:59, Report-20190323_210000
03/24/2019, 18:00:00, 20:59:59, Report-20190323_210000
03/24/2019, 18:00:00, 20:59:59, Report-20190323_210000
03/24/2019, 18:00:00, 20:59:59, Report-20190323_210000
03/24/2019, 18:00:00, 20:59:59, Report-20190323_210000
03/24/2019, 18:00:00, 20:59:59, Report-20190323_210000
03/24/2019, 18:00:00, 20:59:59, Report-20190323_210000
```

Comment: Thank you @dzang, this helped me a lot!

Comment: @krcha glad to hear that. good luck with your task! 
If you are happy with one of the answers given, would be good to mark it as accepted answer. cheers

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer, because I don't know the Python APIs for manipulating text files particularly well.  You may read the first line of the file, and extract out the values for the report date, and start/end window times.

```
first = "ReportDate=03/24/2019, TimeWindowStart=18:00:00, TimeWindowEnd=20:59:59"
ReportDate = re.sub(r'ReportDate=([^,]+),.*', '\\1', first)
TimeWindowStart = re.sub(r'.*TimeWindowStart=([^,]+),.*', '\\1', first)
TimeWindowEnd = re.sub(r'.*TimeWindowEnd=(.*)', '\\1', first)
```

Write out the first line with the values for the three variables removed.

Then, all you need to do is read in each subsequent line and do the following replacements:

```
line = "Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000"
line = re.sub(r'\bDate\b', ReportDate, line)
line = re.sub(r'\b TimeWindowStart\b', TimeWindowStart, line)
line = re.sub(r'\ TimeWindowEnd\b', TimeWindowEnd, line)
```

After processing each line in this way, you may write it to the output file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
import re

#Open file and read line by line
with open("a") as file:
 # Get and process first line
 first_line = file.readline()
 m = re.search("ReportDate=(?P<ReportDate>[0-9/]+), TimeWindowStart=(?P<TimeWindowStart>[0-9:]+), TimeWindowEnd=(?P<TimeWindowEnd>[0-9:]+)",first_line)
 first_line= re.sub(m.group('ReportDate'), "", first_line)
 first_line= re.sub(m.group('TimeWindowStart'), "", first_line)
 first_line= re.sub(m.group('TimeWindowEnd'), "", first_line)
 print(first_line)

 # Process rest of the lines
 for line in file:
    line = re.sub(r'\bDate\b', m.group('ReportDate'), line)
    line = re.sub(r'\bTimeWindowStart\b', m.group('TimeWindowStart'), line)
    line = re.sub(r'\bTimeWindowEnd\b', m.group('TimeWindowEnd'), line)
    print(line.rstrip())
```

Output:

```
ReportDate=, TimeWindowStart=, TimeWindowEnd=

03/24/2019, 18:00:00, 20:59:59, Report-20190323_210000
03/24/2019, 18:00:00, 20:59:59, Report-20190323_210000
03/24/2019, 18:00:00, 20:59:59, Report-20190323_210000
03/24/2019, 18:00:00, 20:59:59, Report-20190323_210000
03/24/2019, 18:00:00, 20:59:59, Report-20190323_210000
03/24/2019, 18:00:00, 20:59:59, Report-20190323_210000
03/24/2019, 18:00:00, 20:59:59, Report-20190323_210000
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code:

```py
import re

s = """ReportDate=03/24/2019, TimeWindowStart=18:00:00, TimeWindowEnd=20:59:59

Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000
Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000
Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000
Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000
Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000
Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000
Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000"""

datereg = r'(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})'
timereg = r'(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})'

dates = re.findall(datereg, s)
times = re.findall(timereg, s)

# replacing one thing at a time
result = re.sub(r'\bDate\b', dates[0],
            re.sub(r'\bTimeWindowEnd\b,', times[1] + ',',
                re.sub(r'\bTimeWindowStart\b,', times[0] + ',',
                    re.sub(timereg, '', 
                        re.sub(datereg, '', s)))))

print(result)
```

Output:

```sh
ReportDate=, TimeWindowStart=, TimeWindowEnd=

03/24/2019, 18:00:00, 20:59:59, Report-20190323_210000
03/24/2019, 18:00:00, 20:59:59, Report-20190323_210000
03/24/2019, 18:00:00, 20:59:59, Report-20190323_210000
03/24/2019, 18:00:00, 20:59:59, Report-20190323_210000
03/24/2019, 18:00:00, 20:59:59, Report-20190323_210000
03/24/2019, 18:00:00, 20:59:59, Report-20190323_210000
03/24/2019, 18:00:00, 20:59:59, Report-20190323_210000
```

Answer (score 0):

Find a clear solution represented below:

```
import re

input_str = """
ReportDate=03/24/2019, TimeWindowStart=18:00:00, TimeWindowEnd=20:59:59
Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000
Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000
Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000
Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000
Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000
Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000
Date, TimeWindowStart, TimeWindowEnd, Report-20190323_210000
"""

# Divide input string into two parts: header, body
header = input_str.split('\n')[1]
body = '\n'.join(input_str.split('\n')[2:])

# Find elements to be replaced
ri = re.findall('\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}',header)
ri.extend(re.findall('\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}',header))

# Replace elements
new_header = header.replace(ri[0],'')\
                   .replace(ri[1],'')\
                   .replace(ri[2],'')

new_body = body.replace('Date',ri[0])\
               .replace('TimeWindowStart',ri[1])\
               .replace('TimeWindowEnd',ri[2])

# Construct the result string
full_string = new_header + '\n\n' + new_body
```

Just find the items to be replaced with regex and perform an ordinary string replace. I think it's effective until you have only few elements.